# Domain redirect only for primary domain not add on domains

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, hosting, cpanel, shared-hosting

I want to redirect all http request to https. The problem I am experiencing is that it redirect all add on domains too. I want to redirect only primary domain. Here is my htaccess code -

This will enable the Rewrite capabilities:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
```

This rule will redirect users from their original location, to the same location but using HTTPS. The leading slash is made optional so that this will work either in httpd.conf
or .htaccess context:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

What can I do to make sure it only redirects on the primary domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect a specific domain from `http` to `https` you can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://% {SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

This will redirect `http://example.com/` to `https://example.com/` .